# last insert data not showing in node js when i redirect from add to show listing

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

in my code when I redirect from add data, in this case, it will not fetch the latest data but when I refresh it will fetch  me that data

```
var CountryResponseData = [];
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    Country.find({}).then(countrylist =>{
        console.log(countrylist);
        if(countrylist){
            CountryResponseData = countrylist;
        }else{
            CountryResponseData = "empty";
        }
    });

    res.render('countrymgmt/list', { layout: "layoutinternal", title: "List Of Countries","countries":CountryResponseData });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will problem because of it taking time to fetching data from database till it renders the view page do u need to do inside promise means do like as follow

```
var CountryResponseData = [];router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
Country.find({}).then(countrylist =>{
    console.log(countrylist);
    if(countrylist){
        res.render('countrymgmt/list', { layout: "layoutinternal", title: "List Of Countries","countries":countrylist });

    }else{
        res.render('countrymgmt/list', { layout: "layoutinternal", title: "List Of Countries","countries":[] });
    }
});
```

});